# Grouping directories in `zsh`

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ls, wildcards

Using `zsh` both of these command produce the same result:

```
ls (dir1|dir2)/dir3/*.txt
ls {dir1,dir2}/dir3/*.txt
```

Using `bash` only the following works:

```
ls {dir1,dir2}/dir3/*.txt
```

So, if I want to list all `.txt` files in multiple specific directories using `zsh` is one of the above preferred or correct? Or, are they equivalent and `zsh` simply offers regex functionality that is lacking in `bash`?

Comment: The Z shell also has `ls ?(dir1|dir2)/dir3/*.txt` when `setopt kshglob` is in effect.

Comment: ... or bash, with `shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you should choose the first version.

`(...)` is a glob operator designed to generate **filenames**, while `{...}`, called a brace expansion, is designed to generate **strings**. In many cases you can switch between them and get the same results as filename is a string, but there are few differences. For example consider that one directory doesn't exist, in such case you would get

```
$ ls (dir1|fakedir)/dir3/*.txt
dir1/dir3/file.txt

$ ls {dir1,fakedir}/dir3/*.txt
zsh: no matches found: fakedir/dir3/*.txt
```

Probably you want the first result. What is important, the error in the second case comes not from brace expansion, but from `*`! If you remove it `ls (dir1|dir1)/dir3` then `ls` claims that it cannot access `fakedir/dir3`, so the error is unpredictable (depends on other stuff).

Another difference is that first version produces only one output in case of repeated directories, whereas second version just outputs many times the same:

```
$ ls (dir1|dir1)/dir3/*.txt
dir1/dir3/file.txt

$ ls {dir1,dir1}/dir3/*.txt
dir1/dir3/file.txt  dir1/dir3/file.txt
```

Again, I believe in most cases user wants the first result.

If you want a full control over globbing mechanism I recommend to acquaint with *glob qualifiers* (see `man zshexpn`).

---

In case of `bash` it is better to set `extglob` option which gives you access to more globs, not as powerful as `zsh`, but still better than brace expansion.

Specifically, the equivalent of `zsh`'s `(foo|bar)` in `bash -O extglob` is `@(foo|bar)` (that syntax comes from ksh).